# How do I get the container over my background picture in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-attachment

I´m currently trying to make a website with twitter bootstrap.
Unfortunately, I can not create a background image so that my container pushes about it. Always pushes the background over my background picture. Can someone tell me how to do this?

[here you can see my problem](https://vid.me/RO9c)

[image: concept]

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700);
body {
  background: #e5e5e5;
  color: #999;
}

header {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.7), rgba(0,0,0,0.7)), url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/343299/pexels-photo-343299.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh; /* 100% of the viewport's height */
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

/*#header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  z-index: 99999;
}*/

.container {
  position:relative
}
.content {
    background-color:red;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.backgroundImage {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}


h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  color: #777;
  font-weight: 300;
}
a {
  color: #52b6ec;
  -webkit-transition: 300ms;
  -moz-transition: 300ms;
  -o-transition: 300ms;
  transition: 300ms;
}
.btn {
  font-weight: 300;
  border: 0;
}
.btn.btn-primary {
  background-color: #52b6ec;
}
.btn.btn-primary:hover,
.btn.btn-primary.active {
  background-color: #1586c3;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: #80c9f1;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}


.box {
  padding: 50px 30px;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
  position: relative;
}

.box.first {
  margin-top: -40px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
.box.last {
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}
.box h2 {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 48px;
}

/* Start: Recommended Isotope styles */
/**** Isotope Filtering ****/
.isotope-item {
  z-index: 2;
}
.isotope-hidden.isotope-item {
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
/**** Isotope CSS3 transitions ****/
.isotope,
.isotope .isotope-item {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  -ms-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  transition-duration: 0.8s;
}
.isotope {
  -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
  -moz-transition-property: height, width;
  -ms-transition-property: height, width;
  -o-transition-property: height, width;
  transition-property: height, width;
}
.isotope .isotope-item {
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform, opacity;
  -ms-transition-property: -ms-transform, opacity;
  -o-transition-property: -o-transform, opacity;
  transition-property: transform, opacity;
}
/**** disabling Isotope CSS3 transitions ****/
.isotope.no-transition,
.isotope.no-transition .isotope-item,
.isotope .isotope-item.no-transition {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0s;
  -ms-transition-duration: 0s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0s;
  transition-duration: 0s;
}
/* End: Recommended Isotope styles */
/* disable CSS transitions for containers with infinite scrolling*/
.isotope.infinite-scrolling {
  -webkit-transition: none;
  -moz-transition: none;
  -ms-transition: none;
  -o-transition: none;
  transition: none;
}

#services .box {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
#services .row > div {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
#team-scroller .designation {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: block;
}
.member {
  margin: 0 50px;
  text-align: center;
}


.navbar-default {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  overflow: hidden;
}
.navbar-default .first a {
  border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 78px;
  background: url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat 0 50%;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li {
  margin-left: 1px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  padding: 30px 25px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a > i {
  display: inline-block;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active:focus > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active:hover > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:hover > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:focus > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active > a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active:focus > a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active:hover > a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:hover > a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:focus > a:focus {
  background-color: #999;
  color: #fff;
}



.icon-lg {
  font-size: 48px;
  height: 108px;
  width: 108px;
  line-height: 108px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block !important;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.icon-md {
  font-size: 24px;
  height: 68px;
  width: 68px;
  line-height: 68px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.icon-color1 {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}
.icon-color2 {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}
.icon-color3 {
  background-color: #3498db;
}
.icon-color4 {
  background-color: #8e44ad;
}
.icon-color5 {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
}
.icon-color6 {
  background-color: #2c3e50;
}
.gap {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.big-gap {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
#footer {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  color: #999;
}
#footer a {
  color: #999;
}
#footer a:hover {
  color: #52b6ec;
}
ul.social {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul.social > li {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
}
ul.social > li > a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
}
ul.social > li > a i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
textarea#message {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  height: 220px;
}
@keyframes scaleUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.3);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes scaleUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.3);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes scaleUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.3);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes scaleUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-transform: scale(0.3);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes scaleUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -o-transform: scale(0.3);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -o-transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>example</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/ico/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="images/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="images/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="images/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="images/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
</head><!--/head-->

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar" data-offset="0">
    <header id="header" role="banner">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">example</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">example</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">example</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">example</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">example</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header><!--/#header-->




    <section id="services">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="box first">
                <div class="center gap">
                    <h2>example</h2>
                </div><!--/.center-->
                <div class="row">
                    <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

                    Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.   

                    Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.   

                    Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.   

                    Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis.   

                    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, At accusam aliquyam diam diam dolore dolores duo eirmod eos erat, et nonumy sed tempor et et invidunt justo labore Stet clita ea et gubergren, kasd magna no rebum. sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua. est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.   

                    Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus.   

                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

                    Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.   

                    Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.   

                    Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                    </p>
                </div><!--/.row-->
            </div><!--/.box-->
        </div><!--/.container-->
    </section><!--/#services-->




    <footer id="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <center>
                    &copy; 2017 <a target="_blank" href="http://example.com" title="example">example</a>. All Rights Reserved.
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer><!--/#footer-->

    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[here a link to my files](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zgvmefuskdfh882/AADMhTNkOp4913Su192faFPMa?dl=0)

Comment: Your example is far from being a [mcve]. Most probably, applying `position:relative` to your `container` will fix your problem. If it doesn't use the snippet tool (`<>` button) linking sufficient resources to reproduce the problem here but (ideally) not more.

Comment: Hello I have uploaded the files to you. Maybe you know what I did wrong?

Comment: Post the code here. I can't download that

Comment: Hello I have post my code here. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to move the page background from header to body?

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700);
body {
  color: #999;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.7), rgba(0,0,0,0.7)), url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/343299/pexels-photo-343299.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
    
.navbar-fixed-top {
  right: none;
  left: none
}

.container.header + * {
  margin-top: 100vh;
}


    .container {
      position:relative
    }
    .content {
        background-color:red;
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 100vh;
    }

    .backgroundImage {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      z-index: 1;
    }


    h1,
    h2,
    h3,
    h4,
    h5,
    h6 {
      color: #777;
      font-weight: 300;
    }
    a {
      color: #52b6ec;
      -webkit-transition: 300ms;
      -moz-transition: 300ms;
      -o-transition: 300ms;
      transition: 300ms;
    }
    .btn {
      font-weight: 300;
      border: 0;
    }
    .btn.btn-primary {
      background-color: #52b6ec;
    }
    .btn.btn-primary:hover,
    .btn.btn-primary.active {
      background-color: #1586c3;
      -webkit-box-shadow: none;
      -moz-box-shadow: none;
      box-shadow: none;
    }
    a:hover,
    a:focus {
      color: #80c9f1;
      text-decoration: none;
      outline: none;
    }


    .box {
      padding: 50px 30px;
      background: #fff;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
      position: relative;
    }

    .box.first {
      margin-top: -40px;
      border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    }
    .box.last {
      border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    }
    .box h2 {
      padding: 10px 30px;
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 4px;
      position: relative;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
      font-size: 48px;
    }

    /* Start: Recommended Isotope styles */
    /**** Isotope Filtering ****/
    .isotope-item {
      z-index: 2;
    }
    .isotope-hidden.isotope-item {
      pointer-events: none;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    /**** Isotope CSS3 transitions ****/
    .isotope,
    .isotope .isotope-item {
      -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
      -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
      -ms-transition-duration: 0.8s;
      -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
      transition-duration: 0.8s;
    }
    .isotope {
      -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
      -moz-transition-property: height, width;
      -ms-transition-property: height, width;
      -o-transition-property: height, width;
      transition-property: height, width;
    }
    .isotope .isotope-item {
      -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
      -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform, opacity;
      -ms-transition-property: -ms-transform, opacity;
      -o-transition-property: -o-transform, opacity;
      transition-property: transform, opacity;
    }
    /**** disabling Isotope CSS3 transitions ****/
    .isotope.no-transition,
    .isotope.no-transition .isotope-item,
    .isotope .isotope-item.no-transition {
      -webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
      -moz-transition-duration: 0s;
      -ms-transition-duration: 0s;
      -o-transition-duration: 0s;
      transition-duration: 0s;
    }
    /* End: Recommended Isotope styles */
    /* disable CSS transitions for containers with infinite scrolling*/
    .isotope.infinite-scrolling {
      -webkit-transition: none;
      -moz-transition: none;
      -ms-transition: none;
      -o-transition: none;
      transition: none;
    }

    #services .box {
      padding-bottom: 0;
    }
    #services .row > div {
      margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
    .center {
      text-align: center;
    }
    #team-scroller .designation {
      margin-top: 10px;
      display: block;
    }
    .member {
      margin: 0 50px;
      text-align: center;
    }


    .navbar.navbar-default {
      background: #fff;
      border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
      border: 0;
      padding: 0;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
      box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .navbar-default .first a {
      border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-brand {
      margin-right: 50px;
      margin-left: 20px;
      width: 200px;
      height: 78px;
      background: url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat 0 50%;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li {
      margin-left: 1px;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
      padding: 30px 25px;
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 18px;
      color: #000;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a > i {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active > a,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active:focus > a,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active:hover > a,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:hover > a,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:focus > a,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active > a:focus,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active:focus > a:focus,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active:hover > a:focus,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:hover > a:focus,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:focus > a:focus {
      background-color: #999;
      color: #fff;
    }



    .icon-lg {
      font-size: 48px;
      height: 108px;
      width: 108px;
      line-height: 108px;
      color: #fff;
      margin: 10px;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      text-align: center;
      display: inline-block !important;
      border-radius: 100%;
    }
    .icon-md {
      font-size: 24px;
      height: 68px;
      width: 68px;
      line-height: 68px;
      color: #fff;
      margin-right: 10px;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      text-align: center;
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .icon-color1 {
      background-color: #e74c3c;
    }
    .icon-color2 {
      background-color: #2ecc71;
    }
    .icon-color3 {
      background-color: #3498db;
    }
    .icon-color4 {
      background-color: #8e44ad;
    }
    .icon-color5 {
      background-color: #1abc9c;
    }
    .icon-color6 {
      background-color: #2c3e50;
    }
    .gap {
      margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
    .big-gap {
      margin-bottom: 100px;
    }
    #footer {
      padding-top: 30px;
      padding-bottom: 30px;
      color: #999;
    }
    #footer a {
      color: #999;
    }
    #footer a:hover {
      color: #52b6ec;
    }
    ul.social {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 10px 0 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    ul.social > li {
      margin: 0 0 20px;
    }
    ul.social > li > a {
      display: block;
      font-size: 18px;
    }
    ul.social > li > a i {
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
    textarea#message {
      padding: 10px 15px;
      height: 220px;
    }
    @keyframes scaleUp {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(0.3);
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1);
      }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes scaleUp {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: scale(0.3);
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
      }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes scaleUp {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.3);
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      }
    }
    @-ms-keyframes scaleUp {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-transform: scale(0.3);
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: scale(1);
      }
    }
    @-o-keyframes scaleUp {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-transform: scale(0.3);
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform: scale(1);
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar" data-offset="0">
<div class="container header navbar-fixed-top">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">Example</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Example</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      
  </nav>
</div>

<section id="services">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box first">
            <div class="center gap">
                <h2>example</h2>
            </div><!--/.center-->
            <div class="row">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut
                    labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
                    et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut
                    labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
                    et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut
                    labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
                    et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

                    Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum
                    dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit
                    praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                    amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna
                    aliquam erat volutpat.

                    Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut
                    aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit
                    esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et
                    iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla
                    facilisi.

                    Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim
                    placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam
                    nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim
                    veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                    consequat.

                    Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum
                    dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis.

                    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
                    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed
                    diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
                    vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
                    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, At
                    accusam aliquyam diam diam dolore dolores duo eirmod eos erat, et nonumy sed tempor et et invidunt
                    justo labore Stet clita ea et gubergren, kasd magna no rebum. sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero
                    voluptua. est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
                    sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.

                    Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
                    aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
                    clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                    amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
                    aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
                    clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                    amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
                    aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
                    clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus.

                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut
                    labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
                    et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut
                    labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
                    et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut
                    labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
                    et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

                    Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum
                    dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit
                    praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                    amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna
                    aliquam erat volutpat.

                    Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut
                    aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit
                    esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et
                    iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla
                    facilisi.

                    Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim
                    placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam
                    nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim
                    veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                </p>
            </div><!--/.row-->
        </div><!--/.box-->
    </div><!--/.container-->
</section><!--/#services-->


<footer id="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <center>
                &copy; 2017 <a target="_blank" href="http://example.com" title="example">example</a>. All Rights
                Reserved.
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer><!--/#footer-->
</body>
```

Updated with fixed header, as per comment request.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your solution almost agrees with what I have imagined. The navigation should always be visible. In addition, the picture should only fill 3/4 of the screen and under it should be white.

Comment: @Moritz I'm afraid nothing in your code or the initial answer suggested you want a fixed header. I did notice you changed the default navbar markup, which I happen to think is a mistake, but I assumed you know what you're doing and did not address, since your question seemed to be on a completely different matter. Normally, I would advise you to create a new question for it but, as this is not a complex feature/request, I will update my answer to make the navigation fixed while keeping it's styling. However, I'm now on mobile and can't edit code for the next couple of hours or perhaps three.